# ArcMap Error 010586 when using Landsat Toolbox Scanline Error Tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, landsat-7, toolbox

I installed the Landsat Toolbox in ArcMap 10.8.2 and I am getting the error 010586 when I load a Landsat 7 band file into the tool. A red X shows up in the form and will not permit me to run the tool.

**ERROR**
010568: Invalid extent. Please check for zero length or width, or failure to project extent to output spatial reference.

**FILE INFORMATION**

Extent Values:
2982015
282585
524715
2769285

Spatial format:
Proejcted
WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_17N
Projection: Transverse_Mercator

Here is what I tried so far:

1. Define the output extent in Environments section
2. Move the image to a shorter file directory length and file name
3. Reproject the file to the same projection
4. Make a copy of the file
5. Clip the extent to a smaller extent

What am I missing here?

I have not seen any posts about this.